# Does wow slider allow remote images

Tags: jquery, wowslider

Good day my fellow geniuses,

I am running into an issue where wow slider isn't able to access the images within it. All images are remote files hosted from a server, so they are not local.

This is causing the page to throw an error "Cannot access local image files"

Does wow slider not allow such method? Or is there an option I can set up? I have searched everywhere and can't seem to find the right answer.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about Wow Slider, but try using bxSlider instead.

http://bxslider.com/

I know it has this capability.